# Генерация большого дерева в Symfony Forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-form, symfony5

Как реализовать дерево в Symfony Forms? На Symfony пишу всего пару недель. 
Пробовал множество способов, по сути форму можно реализовать обычным способом без вспомогательных классов. Хотелось бы все таки разобраться как создать дерево с помощью Symfony Forms, или может это дурная затея?
Форма состоит из множества текстовых полей, возникла именно трудность реализации многоуровневого дерева. 
Есть таблица пользователей, у каждого пользователя имеются свои категории. Всего категорий 3000, да их очень много. В таблице **UserCategory** 227848 записей.

Форму создаю с помощью **\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::createForm**

> Структура дерева

1. Категория 1

   - Категория 2
   - Категория 3

     - Категория 4
   - Категория 7
   - Категория 8

     - Категория 9
     - Категория 10

       - Категория 11
2. Категория 12

> Класс сущности пользователей

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsersRepository")
 */
class Users 
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=254, options={"default":""})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Regex("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/", message="Введите корректный email-адрес.")
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", mappedBy="idUser")
     */
    private $userCats;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userCats = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|UserCategory[]
     */
    public function getUserCats(): Collection
    {
        return $this->userCats;
    }

    public function addUserCat(UserCategory $userCat): self
    {
        if (!$this->userCats->contains($userCat)) {
            $this->userCats[] = $userCat;
            $userCat->setId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUserCat(UserCategory $userCat): self
    {
        if ($this->userCats->contains($userCat)) {
            $this->userCats->removeElement($userCat);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($userCat->getId() === $this) {
                $userCat->setId(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

> Класс сущности категорий

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
* @ORM\Table(indexes={
*     @ORM\Index(columns={"idParent"})
* })
*/
class Category
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=10)
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250, options={"default":""})
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=10)
    */
    private $idParent;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdParent(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idParent;
    }

    public function setIdParent(int $idParent): self
    {
        $this->idParent = $idParent;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

> Класс сущности выбранных категорий пользователя

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserCategoryRepository")
*/
class UserCategory
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users", inversedBy="userCats")
    */
    private $idUser;

    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=10)
    */
    private $idCat;


    public function getIdUser(): ?Users
    {
        return $this->idUser;
    }

    public function setIdUser(?Users $idUser): self
    {
        $this->idUser = $idUser;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdCat(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idCat;
    }

    public function setIdCat(int $idCat): self
    {
        $this->idCat = $idCat;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что реализовать можно с помощью рекурсии.

Comment: Рекурсию можно использовать только в той ситуации, когда создаем обычную форму которая не привязана к сущности. Как говорилось выше, использую Symfony Forms, то есть строитель формы на основе сущности.

Comment: где связь там CollectionType с указанием типа формы который вы и создаете.

Comment: Простите, я вас не совсем понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сущности категории используйте шаблон [nested](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions). В форме укажите группировку по родителю. По идеи, будет тот результат что вы хотите. В прицепе патерн и не обязательно использовать, но в вашем случае желательно, сэкономите на запросах к БД.